# Why doesn't gethostbyname() fail on non-existing host names?

Tags: c, sockets, dns

I'm trying to get an IPv4 address from a host name, so I thought I could use [gethostbyname()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) for that purpose. This works quite well but there is one problem: it doesn't fail when a non-existing host name is passed to it.

Here's some code:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%p\n", gethostbyname("fkldsjflkasdjflkajsdflkjasdf.com"));
    return 0;
}
```

On Ubuntu, the output is:

```
0x7fb891c1b8a0
```

Why isn't it `NULL`?

*** EDIT ***

Here is a more complete example that dumps the result:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname("fkldsjflkasdjflkajsdflkjasdf.com");

    printf("%s %d %d %p\n", hp->h_name, hp->h_addrtype, hp->h_length, hp->h_addr_list);
    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *) hp->h_addr)));

    return 0;
}
```

The result is this:

```
fkldsjflkasdjflkajsdflkjasdf.com 2 4 0x1c141a0
62.138.238.45
```

As you can see, I'm even able to obtain an IP address for the non-existing host name! No idea how this is possible...

Comment: Well, what does the returned struct contain?

Comment: See my edits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem of the DNS server you use. It does not return anything useful when I run the code.

Given that a whois lookup for the returned IP address `62.138.238.45` includes the description `www.t-online.de` I assume that you are using an internet access provided by Deutsche Telekom (T-Online) and that you are using the default name server from T-Online. This name server will not return NXDOMAIN for domains which don't exist but will instead provide an IP address which results in a "helpful" error - i.e. advertisement.

A short test with manually speaking with the HTTP server at this IP and using the domain in question in the `Host` header shows this:

```
$ telnet 62.138.238.45 80
GET / HTTP/1.0 
Host: fkldsjflkasdjflkajsdflkjasdf.com
<newline>
```

This results in:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 30 Dec 2018 19:42:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://navigationshilfe1.t-online.de/dnserror?url=fkldsjflkasdjflkajsdflkjasdf.com/
Content-Length: 267
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://navigationshilfe1.t-online.de/dnserror?url=fkldsjflkasdjflkajsdflkjasdf.com/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

For more information about this "service" and also information on how to disable it see [this information](http://navigationshilfe.t-online.de/dtag/html/dnsephelp.html)  (in German).

Comment: It's likely intentional not a problem. Many ISPs tend to "hijack" dns requests and send you to an ad page for non existing domain names.

Answer (score 1):

What does `h_errno` contain? It should be  `HOST_NOT_FOUND`

[gethostbyname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) only returns null if an internal error occurs, ie it can't allocate the memory for the struct